# Shell Script check if a string contains two in-parameters

Tags: linux, bash, shell, if-statement

I'm taking a intro to Linux and shell script course at Uni. Just came across a problem.

I need to make an if statement that controls if there is only 2 arguments and then write those out and if not return a warning string.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please input two variables: "

read var

if var =  ' '; then
  echo var
else
  echo "More or less than two arguments"
fi
```

This is what I have so far. I thought I could make the if statment look for a space in the string.

This is my first post here on StackExchange. So hello to all fellow StackExchangers out there :=)

Comment: you need to check if there are two arguments on the command line or on the standard output?

Comment: I meant input, sorry. Check my answer for that

Comment: The input should be like "hello world". And the if-statement will check if its two separate words. Not more, not less.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is create an [array](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html) out of your input and then check its length.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please input two variables: "
read var

myArray=($var)

if [ ${#myArray[@]} -eq 2 ];
then
        echo ${myArray[*]}
else
        echo "More or less than two arguments"
fi
```

Values in bash arrays are separated by spaces, so when `var` gets expanded each word is created as a new array index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$#` to check the amount of variables a script is called with. Then use `$1` and `$2` to echo the variables.

```
if [ $# -eq 2 ]
then
    echo "$1 $2"
fi
```

Comment: While true `$#` will give you the number of arguments supplied the input for this question is from stdin, not command line args, so this won't do what's required.

Answer (score 0):

To read two lines from standard input and check they are not empty, you can use the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Please input two variables: "

read var1
read var2

if [ -n "$var1" -a -n "$var2" ]; then
  echo $var1
  echo $var2
else
  echo "More or less than two arguments"
fi
```

I have modified your script to add a new variable (`var2`) and renamed `var` to `var1`.

Then, the `if` is modified to check that both variables are not empty with `-n` switch of `test` (type `help test` on shell to get more info on that). Instead of the command `test`, I have used the more programmer friendly `[`, which does the same as `test`, but needs an ending `]`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of waiting until after the command starts running to take input, just accept command-line arguments. Your script would look like:

```
if (( $# != 2 )); then
    echo "Need exactly two arguments"
    exit 1
fi

# Use $1 and $2 as needed
```

Then call your script with

```
myscript hello world
```